# change css class on click in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to change the CSS class of a div element on click. Below is the code I am trying.
'input-large' should be active by default. 
'input-large input-active' should become active on click on username and becomes inactive on clicking somewhere else.

```html
<div class="input-large">
    <label class="input-label">Username</label>
    <input class="input-field" type="text">
</div>

<div class="input-large input-active">
            <label class="input-label">Username</label>
            <input class="input-field" type="text">
</div>
```

Please let me know how to change the DIVs on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use ng-click and ng-blur 
follow the snippet in :

http://jsfiddle.net/atXAC/11/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<div ng-class="{'active':hasFocus==true,'inactive':hasFocus==false}">Enter your Name here</div>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-click="hasFocus=true" ng-customblur="onBlur()" required id="name"/>

</div>
```

here goes your js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('ngCustomblur', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return function(scope, element, attr) {
    var fn = $parse(attr['ngCustomblur']);      
    element.bind('blur', function(event) {        
      scope.$apply(function() {
        fn(scope, {$event:event});
      });
    });
  }
}]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onBlur = function(){        
        $scope.hasFocus = false;
    }
}
```

please adapt it for your form.. its working

Comment: Hi Ankur, i just saw that the angular version used in the fiddle is 1.0.3. I am using 1.4.8 and i am not able to make the same code work in 1.4.8. could you please let me know how to upgrade this code to 1.4.8?

Answer (score 0):

another approach can be to append the css class in onClick handler in your controller.